# Incluir un archivo xlsx como template en la carpeta static del deploy en genexus

Tags: genexus

quería saber si hay una forma automática desde el IDE de genexus de incluir un archivo estático en el directorio static que se guarda en el war del deploy al momento de deployar la app.
Necesito que al momento de desplegar la aplicación en producción exista un archivo xlsx guardado dentro de la kb para que sea utilizado por el cliente como template.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿El objeto de tipo File serviría para incluir archivos estáticos?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]